# Using variables in folder paths in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables

I'm fairly new to PowerShell. I want to automatically copy config files from remote workstations on the same network and paste them into folders on my local PC.

Currently I'm prompting the user to enter the hostname for the remote computer they want to copy from. I want to pass that along to the folder path.

Like this:

```
$host_name = Read-Host "Please enter the hostname of the remote computer"

Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$host_name\C$\Program Files (x86)\BizTech\Oasis Prime\*" -Include *.config -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\Users\USERPROFILE\Desktop\Configs\$host_name\"
```

Is this even possible? Thank you everyone

Here is the error im getting

`Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\ws4-w7-c630\C$\Program Files (x86)\BizTech\Oasis Prime' because it does not exist. At line:7 char:14 + Get-ChildItem <<<< -Path "\\$host_name\C$\Program Files (x86)\BizTech\Oasis Prime" -Include *.config -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\OPs\Configs\$host_name" + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (\\ws4-w7-c630\C...rat\Oasis Prime:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: What happened during your testing?

Comment: as `Mark Kram` implied, it looks like it would work. [grin] i would likely have left off the final `slash asterisk` on the source path and the final `slash` on the target path, but it really looks like it would work. ///// so ... what happens when you try your code?

Comment: As @Lee_Daily says, but I would first create the destination path if that does not already exist.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone.  Here is the error im getting:
`Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path '\\ws4-w7-c630\C$\Program Files (x86)\BizTech\Oasis Prime' because it does not exist.
At line:7 char:14
+ Get-ChildItem <<<<  -Path "\\$host_name\C$\Program Files (x86)\BizTech\Oasis Prime" -Include *.config -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "C:\OPs\Configs\$host_name"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\ws4-w7-c630\C...rat\Oasis Prime:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand`

Comment: I know the path is correct with the hostname because I can file explorer into it

Comment: Are you first opening a Powershell console “Run as administrator”?

Comment: @chase_work85 - _please_ put the info into your Original Post so that folks can find it without needing to dog for it. [*grin*]

Comment: According to [this](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/powershell_remoting-24/14464/get-childitem-from-remote-machine-using-variable-for-path) you have to invoke the Get-ChildItem on the remote computer.

Comment: Also, your code is wrapped incorrectly. The pipe should be at the end of the previous line. Is that how the code looks in your script? If so, please [edit] your question and fix that. Introducing new bugs when posting a question decreases the chance of getting a solution for the problem you're asking about. If not, that's another thing you need to fix.

Comment: When you are trying to access "Administrative share", i.e. `C$`, you have to be a member of Administrators group on the remote server. Running as administrator on local machine is not required.